# How to find first Thursday of a month using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find First Thursday of this month using oracle?

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'MM')firstday from dual;
```

above is getting firstday of this month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just get the next Thursday after the first day of the month, the *after* part means that if the 1st is itself a Thursday you will acually get a date a week too late. For instance, 2018-02-01 was a Thursday, and putting that into `next_day()` gives you 2018-02-08.

You need to get the next Thursday after the last day of the previous month:

```
next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - 1, 'THU')
```

Demo of both values; look at February, March and November in particular:

```
with t (dt) as  (
  select add_months(date '2018-01-15' , level - 1) from dual connect by level <= 12
)
select next_day(trunc(dt, 'MM'), 'THU') as wrong,
       next_day(trunc(dt, 'MM') - 1, 'THU') as ok
from t;

WRONG       OK
----------  ----------
2018-01-04  2018-01-04
2018-02-08  2018-02-01
2018-03-08  2018-03-01
2018-04-05  2018-04-05
2018-05-03  2018-05-03
2018-06-07  2018-06-07
2018-07-05  2018-07-05
2018-08-02  2018-08-02
2018-09-06  2018-09-06
2018-10-04  2018-10-04
2018-11-08  2018-11-01
2018-12-06  2018-12-06
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with the below SQL

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'),'THURSDAY') FROM DUAL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f585b/1)